# HttpURLConnection giving -1 as content length in header

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to fetch out the content length from an header bfor getting the file size but i am getting it as -1. This is the scenario in case of .pdf or .doc files. It is working fine as per expectations for images.

Following are the two things that i have tried to achieve the same.

1. `int filelength=urlConnection.getContentLength();`

and also tried

1. `final String contentLengthStr=urlConnection.getHeaderField("content-length");`

this is the problem i am facing while downloading a file from a url, and especially when the file to be downloaded is .pdf or .doc file.

The files are present on the server, because by hitting the URL from my system redirect me to download file.

Please help.

Comment: Which HTTP Status code (`conn.getResponseCode()`) do you get? Are the documents static (stored finished in the filesystem of the webserver) or created dynamically by some application server? BTW why do you need the length? Copy the stream to a file or another stream and that's it.

Comment: i need length because i am downloading a file and for that filesize i need the length

Comment: Why do you need the filesize in advance? Could you answer the other questions?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, it seems likely that you fetch the redirect reply instead of the document. You might want to enable redirects:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects(boolean)

Please note that redirects will not occur between http and https pages (and vice versa)